# Proving $\omega=\mathbb{N}_0$

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, induction, set-theory

I've been following ZFC and the only way i manage to prove $\omega=\mathbb{N}_0$, is by first assuming $\mathbb{N}_0$ is a set. Whereas I'd like to use $\omega$ to in fact construct $\mathbb{N}$...
Here's my attempt:

I use notation "$Ind(I)$" for "$\emptyset \in I \wedge \forall x\in I:x^+\in I$".
And $\omega = \bigcap\{A\subset I | Ind(A)\}$

By union axiom we also introduce notation for the natural numbers as:

$0 = \emptyset$,
$1 = 0^+ = \{\emptyset\}$,
$2 = 1^+=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$, etc...
and $\mathbb{N}_0 = \{0,1,2,3,...\}$ the "collection" of numbers constructed above. I now wish to prove that this is in fact a set within ZFC.

I understand how $\omega$ is the smallest inductive set : $\forall Ind(\Gamma): \omega \subset \Gamma$

Now since $\omega$ is inductive and contains $\emptyset$, then it should contain $\mathbb{N}_0$.
Since $\mathbb{N}_0$ is Ind, it should contain the smallest inductive set $\omega$

we hence have $\mathbb{N}_0\subset\omega\ \ \wedge \ \ \omega\subset \mathbb{N}_0$ which implies $\omega = \mathbb{N}_0$

I'm looking for a confirmation that this can be a proper proof
does **hypothesizing that $\mathbb{N}_0$ exists and then prooving it's in fact $\omega$** suffices to claim it comes only from the ZFC axioms?

Comment: We can only prove $a=b$ if we know how $a$ and $b$ are defined. What is your definition of $\omega$ and what is your definition of $\mathbb N_0$?

Comment: So, **What is** $\mathbb N_0$? No one can answer unless the definition is clear.

Comment: I think maybe OP to define $\Bbb N_0$ as the smallest inductive set and then show that $\omega$ has this property: $\omega$ itself is inductive, and is a subset of any inductive set.

Comment: @MH.lee sorry, i intended the set $\mathbb{N}_0$ as the "commonly accepted" set of natural numbers {0,1,2,3,...}, with natural numbers being defined in the way shown in the post.